# How to configure post-receive hook on local server

Tags: git, jenkins, githooks

I'm working on local server with Jenkins and my task now is **to trigger testing script after each git push.**

I tried to do this with post-commit hook, which worked as expected but it ran tests **before** actual changes were made (pushed to repo). Well, its post-commit, so that's expected.

So I decided to use some kind of post-push and found post-receive hook, but its not working at all. Running `sh post-receive` does what I want, `chmod +x` done. What am I doing wrong? Should I use another hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A post-receive hook is a [server-side hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks), run when a Git hosting server received a push.
It is generally set in a bare repo:

```
myBareRepo.git/hooks/post-receive
```

If your Jenkins monitors your repo, you could:

- set your Jenkins job to monitor a bare repo instead:

  ```
  git clone --bare myRepo myRepo.git
  ```
- add the post-receive hook in that bare repo instead
- pushing from your repo to this bare repo

  ```
  cd myRepo
  git remote add origin ../myRepo.git
  git push -u origin master
  ```